# Remove leading and trailing space from a file separated by ~ using shell script

Tags: shell

I have a `dat` file generated though `spool`. In `Spool`, lots of extra spaces are generated so, I would like to remove the leading and trailing spaces from each column.

```
Souvik Bhattacharya~ India   ~ Ericsson ~
```

Now, the expected output should be

```
Souvik Bhattacharya~India~Ericsson~
```

Comment: can you post the snippet of code you've tried and is not providing the expected results?!

Answer (score 1):

```sh
$ echo "Souvik Bhattacharya~ India   ~ Ericsson ~" | sed -e 's/ *~ */~/g'
Souvik Bhattacharya~India~Ericsson~
```